# Reverse axis in JavaPlot

Tags: java, javaplot

I want to plot a graph in JavaPlot with axis 'x' starting on higher numbers (and ending on lower). Just the equivalent of gnuplot's `set xrange [10:0]`.
I've tried doing the same with JavaPlot `p.getAxis("x").setBoundaries(10, 0);`, but it sets the values back to 0, 10.